# xalloc does not name a type

Tags: c++, codeblocks, xalloc

I have written the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <excpt.h>

#define n 100
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    float *x;
    try{x = new float[n];}
    catch (xalloc)
    {
        cerr<<"Out if memory"<<endl;
        exit(1);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

However, the code is giving the error: `error: xalloc does not name a type`

Where am I going wrong and what does this error signify?
How do I correct this error?

Comment: It should be `bad_alloc` not `xalloc`!

Answer (score 2):

`xalloc` is not a type (it's a very obscure method of the `ios_base` class). Somehow I think you are getting confused with `bad_alloc`

```
try
{
    x = new float[n];
}
catch (bad_alloc)
{
    cerr<<"Out if memory"<<endl;
    exit(1);
}
```

Comment: You had used `bad_alloc` as exception handler with `cerr` directly here, can we use `bad_alloc b` ... `cout << b.what() << endl`?

Comment: @RohanBari Yes you can do that. `catch` has a similar syntax to a one argument function declaration, so in `catch (T v)` the variable `v` is optional, and if it's not used it can be omitted.